# How to set a binary value for a angular checkbox based on user input?

Tags: angular

I am completely new to Angular and I am trying to build a simple registration page following this [link](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2018/10/29/angular-7-user-registration-and-login-example-tutorial). I need to send the emailid, username, password, and a 1/0 value based on whether the user has accepted the terms and conditions.

I am using a checkbox to detect whether the user has accepted the terms and conditions.

The problem is that Angular is sending a true/false value to the api and the api expects a 1/0 value.

I have tried setting the value using a isChecked variable. The value gets set alright in the html but while submitting the form, it is still sending true/false value.

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AlertService, UserService, AuthenticationService } from '@/_services';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.component.css']
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
  registerForm!: FormGroup;
  loading = false;
  submitted = false;
  isChecked = false;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService,
    private userService: UserService,
    private alertService: AlertService
  ) {
    // redirect to home if already logged in
    if(this.authenticationService.currentUserValue) {
      this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      username: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)]],
      terms_and_conditions: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  // convenience getter for easy access to form fields
  get f() { return this.registerForm.controls; }

  setTermsAndConditions() {
    this.f.terms_and_conditions.setValue(1);
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    console.log(this.registerForm.value);
    // stop here if form is invalid
    if(this.registerForm.invalid) {
      return;
    }

    this.loading = true;
    this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          this.alertService.success('Registration successful', true);
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        },
        error => {
          this.alertService.error(error);
          this.loading = false;
        });
  }
}
```

component.html (relevant portion):

```
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="checkbox" formControlName="terms_and_conditions" class="form-control" 
            [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.terms_and_conditions.errors}" [value]="isChecked ? 1 : 0">I accept the terms and conditions
    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.terms_and_conditions.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
        <div *ngIf="f.terms_and_conditions.errors.required">You need to agree to our terms and conditions</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can just change the backend api to accept a true/false instead of 1/0, but that would mean that the api is becoming dependent on the way angular defines true/false (For example, if another framework defines it as True/False, then I would have to change the api to take care of that). So, I don't want to do that.

Any suggestions on what's the Angular way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add this line to your `onSubmit()` function and that should do the trick.

```
onSubmit() {
  ...
  // THIS ONE
  this.registerForm.value.terms_and_conditions = this.registerForm.value.terms_and_conditions ? 1 : 0;
  ...
  this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(...);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The below linked solution seems to be a little long, but in case if you someday need a little more customization to your checkbox value. Like if you need a YES if checked and NO if not. Have a look might help you.

[Create a ng-true-value & ng-false-value directive for Angular](https://juristr.com/blog/2018/02/ng-true-value-directive/)

Comment: Thanks. I'll check it out.